# c# tcpListener listen for connection status of multiple clients

Tags: c#

I am attempting to connect multiple clients to a *server* and monitor their connection...

I am trying to get a better understanding of `TcpListener` and `TcpClient` while creating these programs.

I found my server code from another stackoverflow answer as I am looking to get a connection from multiple clients, I have edited it abit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace socket_server
{
    class connect
    {
        public class State
        {
            public Socket workSocket = null;
            public const int bufferSize = 1024;
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public class Server
        {
            public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            private static IPEndPoint findMe()
            {
                IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
                IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 5505);
                return localEndPoint;
            }

            public static void start()
            {
                try
                {
                    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(findMe());
                    TcpClient client;
                    listener.Start();

                    Console.WriteLine("Server IP: {0}\n", findMe());
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Connection...");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(threadProc, client);
                    }

                    Console.ReadKey();
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
            private static void threadProc(object obj)
            {
                try
                {
                    var client = (TcpClient)obj;
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You call this like `connect.Server.start()`

This is my current client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace socket_client
{
    class connect
    {
        public class State
        {
            public Socket workSocket = null;
            public const int bufferSize = 256;
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public class Client
        {
            private const int port = 5505;    
            private static String response = String.Empty;

            private static IPEndPoint findServer()
            {
                IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("10.1.2.30");
                IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
                IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
                return remoteEP;
            }

            public static void start()
            {
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

                Console.WriteLine("Server IP: {0}", findServer().ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Client IP: {0}\n", software.getIPAddress());

                connect(client);
                if (client.Connected)
                    Console.WriteLine("\nConnected to: {0}\n", findServer().ToString());
            }

            private static void connect(TcpClient client)
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Connect(findServer());
                } catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Attempting to connect to: {0}", findServer().ToString());
                    connect(client);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

You call this like `connect.Client.start();`

My classes such as `hardware` and `software` simply just get system information.

**I would like to know how to check if a connection is dropped and respond with a `Console.WriteLine` for both Client and Server.**

**Edit-**

This is what I have *working* for checking to see if a client drops from the server:

```
...
private static void threadProc(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        var client = (TcpClient)obj;

        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
        string data = null;

        try { 
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            int i;
            while((i = stream.Read(bytes,0,bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Console.WriteLine(">{0}: {1}", ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString(), data);
            }
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(">>{0} Lost Connection...", ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You will only be able to detect if a connection was closed when reading on the stream fails, since there is no event which would notify you.

You might raise your own event in the connection-handling class.

But for some reasons, it is possible, that a TCP-Connection drops without a pending `Read()`-call to fail.
So, there is no perfect method, like handling an event, which always notifies you, when the connection broke. So you have to implement some keep-alive mechanism. E.g. send a ping/pong every once in a while and wait for the answer. If there is no answer in a defined time, you can close the connection.